# Is there any way to set all result values in the textfield? It sets only last value as expected but i want all to be set in the resultTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am creating a program which converts a string input to binary/octal string and shows the result in a textfield, but only last value (binary/octal string of 1 individual character ) gets shown as expected. But is there any other way to show all values?

```
    resultTextField = new JTextField();
    resultTextField.setBounds(10,170,200,100);
    resultTextField.setForeground(Color.green);
    resultTextField.setBackground(Color.black);
    resultTextField.setOpaque(true);
    resultTextField.setVisible(visibilty);


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    if (e.getSource()==binaryButton) {
    convertToBinary();//to convert the string to binary string
    }
    
    if(e.getSource()== octaButton) {
    convertToOcta();//to convert to octal string
    }       
}   

public void convertToBinary() {
visibilty = true;
```

converting input text (maintextField (String)) to char array

```
char[] textArray = mainTextField.getText().toCharArray(); 
for(int ascii : textArray)//this will convert individual characters to their ascii value
{
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(ascii);//converts ascii value to binary string
    resultTextField.setText(binaryString); //to get result
    resultTextField.setVisible(visibilty);
    //System.out.println(binaryString);
    }
}
```

same thing but as in converToBinary but input gets converted octal string

```
public void convertToOcta() {
visibilty = true;
String text = mainTextField.getText();
char[] textArray = text.toCharArray();
for(int ascii : textArray)
{
String octalString = Integer.toOctalString(ascii);
    resultTextField.setText(octalString);
    //System.out.println(octalString); 
    }
resultTextField.setVisible(visibilty);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include the contents that were already there

```
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(ascii);//converts ascii value to binary string
resultTextField.setText(resultTextField.getText() + binaryString); //to get result
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add/remove text from a text component a `DocumentEvent` is generated. Of course, for this simple task, you probably don't care about the DocumentEvents, but it is something to consider for the future when working with text components.

You could use simple code like:

```
resultTextField.setText( resultTextField.getText() + octalString );
```

This approach will result in multiple `removeUpdate()` and `insertUpdate()` events, when in reality you probably only want to generate a single `insertUpdate()` event. Also this is relatively inefficient since every time you set the text you need to clear all the text in the Document and then rebuild the Document with the new text.

Another option is to update the Document of the text field:

```
Document doc = resultTextField().getDocument().
doc.insertString(...).
```

This will result in multiple `insertUpdate()` events. Also, note that you will need to use try/catch logic to handle an Exception on the `insertString(...)` method.

A simpler approach might be to use a single line `JTextArea`, then you can just use the `append(...)` method to append new text. It updates the Document as shown above, but it already handles the Exception logic so you don't need to worry about it.

```
//resultTextField.setText(octalString);
resultTextArea.append(octalString);
```

This will result in multiple `insertUpdate()` events being generated.

Or if you really want to use a `JTextField` then you can first use a `StringBuffer` and append each String as it is converted. Then outside your loop you can set the text once. Something like:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

for(int ascii : textArray)
{
    String octalString = Integer.toOctalString(ascii);
    //resultTextField.setText(octalString);
    buffer.append(octalString);
}

resultTextField.setText(buffer.toString());
```

Only a single `insertUpdate()` event will be generated.